# Como conectar as caixas de dialogo no QTdesigner e executar py a partir delas?

Tags: qt, python-2.7, gui, qtgui

Sou novo em programação em `python` e já tenho algumas dúvidas. 
Um amigo criou para mim dois códigos em `py` utilizando *pu 2.7*, *Numpy* e *SciPy*. Eu criei uma interface para esses códigos mas não sei como conecta-los.

Criei utilizando o `QTdesigner`. Tem um menu principal, e algumas caixas de dialogo. Não sei como conectar o menu as janelas de dialogo e nem como fazer com que ao clicarmos no menu, este execute um codigo py.

É possível fazer com que a interface abra um arquivo de texto? Como um texto de ajuda?

Comment: Respondendo as perguntas. Sim é possível, mas para que consigamos te ajudar da melhor forma possível, recomendo que coloque o código que você possui até o momento.

Comment: @BrumazziDB como postar o código se ele é grande demais para postar aqui?

Comment: não tem como vc colocar no git, ou algum outro lugar?